# Zakat question for new car purchase

Tags: zakat

Salam - question about a specific scenario with example numbers :

- Assume i had 50K last year this time in my bank account ( since this for more than a year - i owe zakat on this money)
- now lets i made another 50K during the year
- then i also spent 40K on a a new car purchase during the year

the question i have is where this 40K car money comes from :

- if i deduct it from orignal 50K savings - then my Zakat eligibity would only be on 50-40 = 10K
- on other hand - if i deduct it from the earnings throughout the year - then my zakat will be on all 50K which i had more than a year.

what is the right thing to do here ??

JAZK

Comment: As is written I guess a time line with corresponding data is necessary because I don't think you made 50K at once.